# Android - Application listens for email response

Tags: android, sqlite, email

I have just got a button in my application sending an email to all email addresses stored in a sqlite database. I am now wondering can my application listen to my email account and trigger a tick or an x depending on if the email addresses respond with yes or no? I may be completely out of my depth here, but if someone can explain to me how its done, or send me in the direction of a tutorial, it would be great.